# Finding HEX value at a specific offset in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, filestream, binaryreader

I'm trying to figure out how to read a section of bytes (Say 16) starting at a specific address, say 0x2050. I'd like to get the 16 bits output in hex values into a label.

I've been trying to figure out BinaryReader, and FileStreams but I'm not entirely sure what the difference is, or which one I should be using.

*I've seen a lot of threads mentioning file size could be an issue, and I'd like to point out that some files I'll be checking may be up to 4gb in size.

---

I've tried the following:

```
Dim bytes() As Byte = New Byte(OpenedFile.Length) {}
ListBox1.Items.Add(Conversion.Hex(OpenedFile.Read(bytes, &H2050, 6)))
```

But this simply writes 6 bytes to the file, and I'm not sure why. There is no output in the listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like the following?:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim pos As Long = 8272
    Dim requiredBytes As Integer = 2
    Dim value(0 To requiredBytes - 1) As Byte
    Using reader As New BinaryReader(File.Open("File.bin", FileMode.Open))
        ' Loop through length of file.
        Dim fileLength As Long = reader.BaseStream.Length
        Dim byteCount As Integer = 0
        reader.BaseStream.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        While pos < fileLength And byteCount < requiredBytes
            value(byteCount) = reader.ReadByte()
            pos += 1
            byteCount += 1
        End While
    End Using

    Dim displayValue As String
    displayValue = BitConverter.ToString(value)
End Sub
```

Comment: This results in a "File in use" flag getting thrown up, and it writes 6 bytes to the file (deleting all of the contents).

Comment: Seems to be working once I cleaned up the code, let me test just a little bit further.

Comment: The above code has no statements which would write to a file...and if a "File in use" flag appeared, then that indicates it was unable to obtain access to the file for read or write operations.  Are you running this against a file that is already open in another application?

Comment: Hi, I got this working great, thanks again. But I was wondering, how can I remove the hyphens from the output? I can't seem to find where it's being set anywhere. It's creating a problem when I try to convert the HEX into ASCII

Comment: Glad it's working! If the hyphens are giving trouble, you can replace the hyphen with something else, like this: `displayValue = BitConverter.ToString(value).Replace("-", " ")`.  Also, if you would like to get the ASCII string directly from the byte array, you can do this: `displayValue = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(value)`.